# Google Search Console API - SearchAnalytics 500 error

Tags: php, api, google-search-console

I'm trying to get some data out of the Search Console Api, using the SearchAnalyticsQuery.

First i've tried it with PHP:

```
     $this->client->setAccessToken( \Session::get('access_token') );

        $webmaster =  new \Google_Service_Webmasters( $this->client );

        $q = new \Google_Service_Webmasters_SearchAnalyticsQueryRequest();

        $q->setStartDate('2015-01-01');

        try {

            $webmaster->searchanalytics->query('http://example.com', $q);

        } catch(\Exception $e )
        {
            dd($e);
        }
```

I've got a valid token, it does the requests but always returns the following:

```
Error calling POST https://www.googleapis.com/webmasters/v3/sites/example.com/searchAnalytics/query: (500) Backend Error
```

To make sure it wasn't caused by the PHP code, i have also tried it with the Google Api Explorer.

Same results here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hWECi.png

I am currently using the dev-master version of https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client

There must be something i'm doing wrong, i just cant figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't set `endDate` (required parameter) - see [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/webmaster-tools/v3/searchanalytics/query#request-body).

Comment: I'll try this out asap! Thanks! Did you just make an account to tell me this? ^^

Comment: No problem, yes I did because Search Console API is quite easy to use.